# Modification of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a program in VBA, that will change color of cell depending on the type. And if the value is negative, font will be bold. 
My code:

```
Sub Tables()
    Dim N As Integer
    Dim M As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    M = InputBox("Number of columns")
    N = InputBox("Number of rows")
    For i = 0 To N
        For j = 0 To M
            If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value) = True Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Cells(i, j).Value) = True Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
            ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsLogical(Cells(i, j).Value) = True Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsErr(Cells(i, j).Value) = True Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf IsDate(Cells(i, j).Value) = True Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            ElseIf Cells(i, j).HasFormula = True Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
            ElseIf IsNumeric(Cells(i, j).Value) = True Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Else
                Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
            End If
            If Cells(i, j).Vallue < 0 Then
                Cells(i, j).Font.Bold = True
            End If


        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I got:

> Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: 1 there is a typo on `If Cells(i, j).Vallue < 0 Then` 2. that line will also fail when the cell contains an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no row or column 0.

`i` and `j` should start at `1`.

Also as already pointed out, `If Cells(i, j).Value < 0 Then` will fail if the cell contains an error value, and will *also* fail if the cell contains text. Make sure to check if it's a number first.

```
If IsNumeric(Cells(i, j).Value) Then
```

Or just move the "negative" logic earlier:

```
ElseIf IsNumeric(Cells(i, j).Value) = True Then
    Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    If Cells(i, j).Value < 0 Then
         Cells(i, j).Font.Bold = True
    End If
Else
```